# Swapping the PCB of a HDD, how to make sure to have the right firmware?

Tags: hard-drive, repair

I have got a broken HDD, it is not recognized in any way in my operating system. I took the model number "st100LM024" and ordered a used one on ebay.
Unfortuneately I didn't know that these HDD's can have different firmwares on the PCB.
I swapped the PCB's anyway, but without success.

On the small sticker I see the following:

```
W6 REV.6
20120807
U3A 0GD8
```

is this the info about the firmware on the plate? 
I want to buy the correct HHD "again", so can anyone explain me what I have to look for?

[image: HDD]

Comment: Are you sure it's the PCB at fault? There are many variations of drives even with the same model numbers. You'd likely need to be certain every IC model matches the ones on your original, and even then there could be small revision differences that may not work. If you can find a hard drive of the same model manufactured around the same month as your original one you'd probably have the best chance, but this isn't something I've tried before.

Comment: I am not sure if it's the PCB. But buying a used or defective Disk for around 40 Euros is worth getting the data back. The HDD I bought has "W3 REV.3 - 20120814 - M4A 1694"

Comment: Assuming the photo you posted is the drive you're trying to revive, you'd at least want to match the W6 REV.6 I'd assume. Even that may not be enough though, some hard drives have a BIOS chip which will be the only one able to read the data from the platters, you would need to remove the chip from the bad drive and replace the donor board with it.

Comment: okay, I will try to find one :)

Answer (score 0):

The only reliable way I know to ensure the board has the same firmware as the original is to use a take-off from the same model and date series hard disk.  It's probably possible to read out the ROM with the right equipment, but it's not cost effective unless you're trying to recovery critical data from the platters.

For the latter purpose, it's also possible (with the right very expensive equipment) to read out the raw bits from the platter surface, but if there are encoding changes from version to version, it may be challenging to interpret the bits to recover files.

Comment: thank you, yes I understand but I wanted to try my "luck" for at max. 100 Euro.